# How to make ls work as if it was outputting to terminal?

Tags: ls

Colors can be adjusted with --color=always, but how to make it display the columns with default settings, nicely fitted to terminal window size?

Comment: with the `-C` option

Comment: If ls isn't outputting to a terminal, it won't know the window size, so `ls -C` is going to use either the value of the `COLUMNS` environment variable or the number 80. Can you tell us the width you need ls to use?

Comment: Ok, I saw that ```-C``` output is different and assumed it's something I don't want. How to make it use ```COLUMNS```?

Comment: It's using it by default.

Comment: You may also want the `-q` option; that's also turned on by default when the output is to a tty.

Comment: @mosvy It doesn't look like it does that by default to me. When I use ```ls``` the output is wider than with ```ls -C | cat```

Comment: `COLUMNS` has to be exported.

Comment: What do you mean? When I ```echo $COLUMNS``` it outputs the correct number.

Comment: I mean `export COLUMNS`. It doesn't matter if that variable is set in your shell and you can echo it, you have to export it in the environment in order to be seen by `ls`. Not all shells set, update or export the `COLUMNS` variable by default.

Comment: @mosvy thank you, that worked. Can I make it use some other number?